# How to add verbose_name to forms

Tags: django

How to add `verbose_name` to forms in Django?

In forms.py:

```
class SendOrderForm(forms.Form):
   send_option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Send.objects.all(), verbose_name="Send Options")
```

This is not correct

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think, [label argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.label) is what you need:

```
class SendOrderForm(forms.Form):
   send_option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Send.objects.all(), label="Send Options")
```

Comment: how to force label to use default verbose_name from model?

Comment: I can specify labels, but then I need to specify widgets and I do not know how to map model fields to widgets automaticaly:

    class MyForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
            labels = {}
            widgets = {}
    
        for field in Meta.fields:
            if field not in Meta.labels:
                Meta.labels[field] = Meta.model._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name.title()
            if field not in Meta.widgets:
                Meta.widgets[field] = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

Comment: Hey really helpful, can you please tell me one more thing how to change Multichoice filter name like if field is **student_result** so currently filter title is showing **Available StudentResult** I want to change that name. Thanks is advance.